# How do I map Objects in this scenario using c# AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

This is the Source Object I want to map

```
 public class Post
{ 
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; } 
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

This destination object i want to map the source to

```
 public class PostResponse
{
    public int PostId { get; set; } 
    public string PostTitle { get; set; } 
    public  IEnumerable<CommentObj> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Controller throwing the error 
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

```
    [HttpGet(ApiRoutes.Posts.GetAll)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    { 
            var posts = await _postServices.GetPostsAsync();
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<PostResponse>>(posts)); 
    }
```

This is the Service

```
    public async Task<List<Post>> GetPostsAsync()
    { 
            var queryable = _dataContext.Posts.AsQueryable();
            var psts = await queryable.Include(x => x.Comments).ToListAsync();
            return psts; 
    }
```

This is the Mapping Profile

```
    public DomainResponseProfile()
    {

        CreateMap<Post, PostResponse>().
        ForMember(dest => dest.Comments, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Comments.Select(x => new CommentResponse
        { PostId = x.PostId, DateCommented = x.DateCommented })));
    }
```

This is the Domain Comment Object

```
public class Comment
{ 
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }  
}
```

This is the Response Comment Object

```
 public class CommentResponse
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; } 
    public List<CommentObj> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you could be having circular references. Parent pointing to child and child pointing back to parent. You either need to take them out, use max depth/ perservereference, or manually map and ignore properties that cause this. Also check the CommentObj model, or you can post it here as well.

Comment: How much time have you spent researching this? And how much time would it have taken to simply do it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what I did wrong.

```
 wrong  

CreateMap<Post, PostResponse>().
    ForMember(dest => dest.Comments, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Comments.Select(x => new CommentResponse
    { PostId = x.PostId, DateCommented = x.DateCommented })));
```

right

```
   CreateMap<Post, PostResponse>().
        ForMember(dest => dest.Comments, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
  src.Comments));
```

Comment: Actually the `ForMember` is useless :)